Race Conditions in running tests across browsers
I came across a scenario where I'm getting race conditions even with workers = 1 if testing with multiple browsers.
Firefox and Chrome work fine but it's the WebKit that's failing/passing at random.
Consider a record to be inserted via a form following a delete. All 3 browsers will be inserting and deleting a record in sequence but I feel browsers (webkit is the one) are jumping ahead in parallel instead of in a sequence. username is the primary key.
await page.goto("http://localhost:4173/");

// insert
const random = Math.random();
await page.locator('input[id="first"]').fill('John');
await page.locator('input[id="last"]').fill('Doe');
await page.locator('input[id="username"]').fill('johndoe' + random);
await page.waitForFunction(() => {
    const button = document.querySelector('#form button.primary');
    return button && !button.disabled;
});
await page.locator('#form button.primary').click();

// delete
await page.getByText('johndoe' + random).click();
await page.locator('#list footer button[id="delete"]').click();

Consider if we remove the random part; then for all 3 browsers (maybe just webkit), this becomes a single shared record that they are racing to insert and delete.
If you assign a random number, then essentially each browser works to insert and delete it's own individual record, and the unit test passes reliably.
For the time being, I solved it using a random number joining with the username but I feel there has to be a better solution.
Playwright config
workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
projects: [
    {
        name: 'chromium',
        use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },
    {
        name: 'firefox',
        use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },
    {
        name: 'webkit',
        use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    },
]


Are you positive that process.env.CI is resolving to true? If you hard-code the workers value to 1, do you still encounter the race condition? Workers' default value is "half of the number of logical CPU cores." https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-workers

I hardcoded the value to 1, on a different note, webkit is getting stuck and timing out at page.waitForFunction. The button.primary is initially disabled and switches to enabled once all the fields are filled in.

I can confirm that with hardcoded value to 1, that browsers appear to be not racing and are sequentially processing but getting stuck at waitForFunction if I remove random. Once I put random back, the timeout starts to occur. Since worker issue is solved, it's another problem now.

oh I caught something in the headless mode, playwright fails to fill one of the input fields, and as a result, the button never gets enabled.

This could use a runnable [mcve], with a target page that reproduces the failure. There are no obvious problems with this code at a glance. Generally, avoid random numbers and other forms of nondeterminism in testing, though. The goal is to make the same thing happen on every run so failures always fail and passes always pass. The extent to which you don't achieve that, issues arise. I don't see harm in this usage of randomness, but it's not a good smell. Just hardcode something in.

@ggorlen its a good example as it gets.

@AppDeveloper I disagree--nobody has http://localhost:4173/ except you. Give us that site or pick a public site that reproduces the problem. Having answered hundreds of Playwright questions, there are better questions that are fully runnable, verifiable and answerable. If I can't run your code, all I can do is eyeball or guess, and this code passes the eyeball test. You've received a guess answer that didn't work, because your code isn't reproducible. Feel free to leave it up fishing for guess answers, but I can tell you your odds of getting a satisfactory answer are slim.

It's pretty clear that's a bug that should be raised with Playwright. You could of course mock the API, but that's not what you're asking.

as the title suggested, it was a race condition problem, workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined was culprit

Welcome to the cross-browser test automation, this is how it works here ;)
At least for WebKit. Before it was much worse, with IE and specific driver for it.
What you can do:

Ignore WebKit/IE if it's not mandatory. Just kidding :)
Write browser-specific code:

test("Example", async ({ browserName }) => {
  if (browserName === "webkit") {
    // Do something specific for WebKit
  } 
});


Use better locators as Playwright docs suggests, locate by role and following - https://playwright.dev/docs/locators . No xpath/css, as WebKit may fail for some reason there.
Use native waiters and assertions https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions instead of waitForFunction.

await page.waitForFunction(() => {
    const button = document.querySelector('#form button.primary');
    return button && !button.disabled;
});
await page.locator('#form button.primary').click();

In your example, it's not needed. PW click ensures that the button exists and is enabled before the click - see https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-click.
It is still not clear why you need random - but if you need browser unique value try user_${browserName}
await page.getByText(`johndoe_${browserName}`).click();


Thanks for the tips, but random is what I was after. I was forced to use random to make a record unique for each browser in order to pass tests, didn't have a choice. And the question is about that, I shouldn't be using random or browserName because workers=1. Browsers are racing/fighting over this record.

or maybe this was the problem workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,

had to use waitForFunction because reactjs is slow enabling the button from the disabled state.

Playwright have its own waiting mechanisms - idk why you need waitForFunction.

Do you have any traces or errors? It's hard to understand what issues and where you have
